# I cannot stop my php form from sending if fields are blank

Tags: php, forms, email, contact-form, formfield

My form is driving me crazy, it should all be set up to stop sending if fields are empty but it always goes through. If none or all are filled it it will always show my 'Thanks, your message successfully sent' message.

This is my form:

```
<?php 
//////////////////////////
//Specify default values//
//////////////////////////

//Your E-mail
$your_email = 'myemail';

//Default Subject if 'subject' field not specified
$default_subject = 'From My Contact Form';

//Message if 'name' field not specified
$name_not_specified = 'Please type a valid name';

//Message if 'message' field not specified
$message_not_specified = 'Please type a vaild message';

//Message if e-mail sent successfully
$email_was_sent = 'Thanks, your message successfully sent';

//Message if e-mail not sent (server not configured)
$server_not_configured = 'Sorry, mail server not configured';


///////////////////////////
//Contact Form Processing//
///////////////////////////
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST['message']) and isset($_POST['name'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['name']))
        $sender_name  = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['name'])));

    if(!empty($_POST['message']))
        $message      = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['message'])));

    if(!empty($_POST['email']))
        $sender_email = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])));

    if(!empty($_POST['subject']))
        $subject      = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['subject'])));


    //Message if no sender name was specified
    if(empty($sender_name)) {
        $errors[] = $name_not_specified;
    }

    //Message if no message was specified
    if(empty($message)) {
        $errors[] = $message_not_specified;
    }

    $from = (!empty($sender_email)) ? 'From: '.$sender_email : '';

    $subject = (!empty($subject)) ? $subject : $default_subject;

    $message = (!empty($message)) ? wordwrap($message, 70) : '';

    //sending message if no errors
    if(empty($errors)) {
        if (mail($your_email, $subject, $message, $from)) {
            echo $email_was_sent;
        } else {
            $errors[] = $server_not_configured;
            echo implode('<br>', $errors );
        }
    } else {
        echo implode('<br>', $errors );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add `required` attribute to each element of the field you wan't to be filled before form is submitted!

Comment: Aah... functions are a wonderful invention, aren't they? You can `throw` if an invalid argument was provided, or `return false` if something didn't quite work out, long before you reach a `mail()` call

Comment: Can you also add `not empty` check into the if condition ? like `!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['message'])`

Answer (score 1):

**CLIENT SIDE METHOD** Add `required` attribute to each element of the field you wan't to be filled before form is submitted!

**SERVER SIDE METHOD**

If you wan't to do it on server side check if the field is not empty and otherwise redirect back:

```
if(!(isset($_POST['message']) and isset($_POST['name'])))
    header('locaition: formurl');
```

**Most recommended:** Any client-side validation MUST be repeated server-side

Comment: Server-side validation ***is very much recommended*** Never, ever, claim the contrary: If you validate client-side, but the client disables JS, then you might just end up with invalid data being submitted and processed. ***Any client-side validation MUST be repeated server-side***

Comment: I was suggesting, for this question. I'd edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

***Imporant, but slightly off-topic***

Though this does not really answer your question, I do urge you to look into Mail-injection. Whenever you decide to send a mail message using client-data, you are at risk. You don't seem to be sanitizing the data enough.
I have reviewed code on a couple of occasions that did similar things (sending mails with PHP, or processing contact forms). What I had to say about that, especially on the subject of mail-injection can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49901/is-my-php-code-vulnerable-to-xss/50915#50915), and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36330/critique-sanitized-user-email-php-script/36354#36354). Both code-reviews contain links that might also be worth reading.

---

Anyway, to answer your question:

If you don't want PHP to reach a certain statement (ie: `mail()`) in when something goes wrong, use code that allows you to control the flow (stop execution before the statement is reached).
The simplest, and easiest way to do this is through use of a function:

```
/**
 * Sends mail using data in $data argument
 * requires $fields to be an assoc array where
 * keys == field names, and values = null|| default value
 * null for required fields, default value for optional fields
 * If $data is invalid, an InvalidArgumentException is thrown
 * @param array $data
 * @param array $fields
 * @return bool mail() return value
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
function sendMail(array $data, array $fields)
{
    foreach ($fields as $field => $val)
    {
        if (isset($data[$field]))
        {//data is set
            if ($field === 'email')
            {//sanitize
                $val = filter_var($data[$field], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                if (!filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                {//if email is not valid, throw exception
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                        sprintf(
                            'invalid %s value: %s',
                             $field,
                             $data[$field]
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            else
            {//basic, crude sanitation, not enough to protect agains mail injection
                $data[$field] = nl2br(strip_tags(trim($data[$field])));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!$val)
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                    sprintf(
                        '%s is a required field',
                        $field
                    )
                );
             $data[$field] = $val;
        }
    }
    return mail('your_email', $data['subject'], wordwrap($data['message'],70), 'From: '.$data['email']);
}
```

Note that I added special sanitation/validation checks for email addresses. A function worth remembering is [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/filter_var). It has special constants to validate and/or sanitize values. [See which filters are available here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php).

Now this code may seem quite verbose (and it is). If you want, you could easily replace all the `throw new InvalidArgumentException` statements with a simple `return 'The error message string';` statement. This will change the way you *use* this function.
With the exceptions being thrown, you use the function like so:

```
if ($_POST)
{//if there is post data
    try
    {//try - catch block
        //which fields are required, which have default values, defined here
        $validate = array(
            'email'   => null,//required
            'message' => null,//required
            'name'    => 'No Name',//default val,
            'subject' => 'Default subject'//default
        );
        //call function, check what it returns
        if (sendMail($_POST, $validate))
            echo 'Message was sent';//echos if return value was true
        else//if false:
            echo 'failed to send message';
    }
    catch(InvalidArgumentException $e)
    {//if an exception was thrown
        echo 'Error: ', $e->getMessage();//echo the error message
    }
}
```

Now, assume we've replaced all the `throw` statements with a simple `return 'error-string';` statement. Now the usage looks like this:

```
if ($_POST)
{
    $validate = array();//same array as above
    $return = sendMail($_POST, $validate);
    if ($return === true)//use type and value check: ===, not ==
        echo 'Message sent';
    elseif ($return === false)
        echo 'Failed to send message';
    else
        echo 'Error: ', $return;//$return is a string: error message returned by function
}
```

That would be *my* way to tackle your problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fairly easy, you are not telling your script to stop if one of them is empty.

Add this as follows to your script:

```
if($errors) {
    foreach($errors as $value) {
         echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
    exit();
}
```

This will stop your script after sending the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
(...)
///////////////////////////
//Contact Form Processing//
///////////////////////////
$errors = array();
if(!empty($_POST['message']) and !empty($_POST['name'])) {
(...)
```

In case it's still wrong, make sure fields are really empty.

```
(...)
///////////////////////////
//Contact Form Processing//
///////////////////////////
$errors = array();
if(!empty($_POST['message']) and trim($_POST['message']) and !empty($_POST['name']) and trim($_POST['name'])) {
(...)
```